# Open ports for accessing GCM servers (hostname, IP and ports needed)

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

We have a requirement for a project to send push notifications to Android devices. From what I understand, GCM is the way to go. My company network team needs to open firewall ports for us to connect to GCM to send push notifications. We need to do so for development and production environment. I am not sure if GCM has a development environment. Here are my questions:

(1) android.apis.google.com ports 5228,5229. What is/are the IP address(es)to specify for this server?

(2) android.googleapis.com ports 5230 and 443. What is/are the IP address(es) to specify for this server?

(3) Is there a development environment for GCM? If yes, then what is/are the GCM server hostnames, IP addresses and ports?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no need to specify IP address. see this for details. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm

Comment: Is there a separate set of development GCM servers? I know that for iOS, they do have separate development and production APNS servers.

Answer (score -1):

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#auth):

> If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or
>   from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow connectivity with
>   FCM in order for your Firebase Cloud Messaging client apps to receive
>   messages. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. FCM typically
>   only uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. FCM doesn't
>   provide specific IPs, so you should allow your firewall to accept
>   outgoing connections to all IP addresses contained in the IP blocks
>   listed in Google's ASN of 15169.

Comment: From what I know, Google's ASN of 15169 contains many IP addresses. It would not be practical to list all the IP addresses contained there.